# Switch tab with form control button on a different form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a form with 5 static tabs and then created 5 separate forms that load in to them at Main form load. The first of these tabs has buttons on the form that I want to link to and show the corresponding tab when clicked.

The problem I'm having is that the buttons not being on the main form but a separate form don't have the options to switch to the corresponding tab on the main form.

I have tried the `tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2` stumped me for a couple of days this one any help much appreciated

Comment: Please post code to clarify your question. Hard to understand the problem

Comment: Please paste some code here for us to start.

Comment: If you are using the Windows Forms `TabControl`, then you should change the `SelectedIndex`.  See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have the form raise an event when the button is clicked.  You can subscribe that event in your main form and change the SelectedIndex property.

Comment: Thanks. I will endeavour to post code on future questions if I have any which I'm sure I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, your problem is "How to communicate the button click on the sub form to the main form".

I'd suggest to declare events in your sub forms and catch these events in your main form. So a simplified example of a sub form could look like this:

```
public class SubForm : Form
{
    // this is the event to register with from MainForm
    public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
    // thread safe event invocator (standard pattern)
    protected virtual void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        EventHandler handler = ButtonClicked;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // your button handler
    private void button1_Clicked(object sender, Eventargs e)
    {
        OnButtonClicked();
    }
}
```

And in your main form you could do the following:

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private SubForm _subForm1 = new SubForm();
    private SubForm _subForm2 = new SubForm();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        // more initializatino

        _subForm1.ButtonClicked += subForm1_ButtonClicked;
        _subForm2.ButtonClicked += subForm2_ButtonClicked;
    }

    private void subForm1_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
    }
    private void subForm2_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
    }
```

And you can also think about using only one `someSubForm_ButtonClicked` handler and infer which tab to select via the `sender` argument, which will be the `SubForm` that raised the event.

Comment: Ah yes that is just what I wanted Rene, makes sense to me now, all about the communication between them, thanks very much.